# Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'keyboardType' of value - ReactNative

Tags: react-native

I'm having a warning saying

`Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'keyboardType' of value "supplied to 'TextInput' expected one of ["default", "email-address", etc]`

What I am trying to do is changed the `keyboardType` based on the selected `dropdown`.

Is working fine but I still keeps on having this error. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I'm still new to React and ReactNative, if someone could help me explaining on how things work and giving me example how to do it, it will be really appreciated.

Here's my code

```
import ModalDropdown from 'react-native-modal-dropdown'; 

const types = ['Phone', 'Email Address', 'Name', 'Address'];
export default class SampleComponent extends Component{
 constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  dataInput: '',
  typeOfKeyboard: '',
};
}

// this is how I set the state to be inputed in my `keyboardType` props 
 typeSelectedOnSelect(id, value) {

if(value== 'Phone'){
  this.setState({typeOfKeyboard: 'numeric'});
}else if(value== 'Email Address'){
  this.setState({typeOfKeyboard: 'email-address'});
}else{
  this.setState({typeOfKeyboard: 'default'});
}
}

render(){

 <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
                  <Text style={styles.contactTypeText}>Contact Type</Text>
                  <ModalDropdown
                              options={types}
                              onSelect={this.contactTypeOnSelect.bind(this)}
                              style={styles.dropdownContainer}
                              dropdownStyle={styles.dropdownStyle}
                              textStyle= {styles.dropdownText}
                  />

   <TextInput label="Type anything" keyboardType={this.state.typeOfKeyboard}  onChangeText={(dataInput)=>this.setState({dataInput})} value={this.state.dataInput} />
                </View>
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your initial state for `typeOfKeyboard` is empty.

Change it to : 'default' or pass it null.
From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardtype)

> keyboardType?: enum('default', 'email-address', 'numeric',
>   'phone-pad', 'ascii-capable', 'numbers-and-punctuation', 'url',
>   'number-pad', 'name-phone-pad', 'decimal-pad', 'twitter',
>   'web-search')
>
> Determines which keyboard to open, e.g.numeric.
>
> The following values work across platforms:
>
> default numeric email-address phone-pad

The '?' signifies that is not required

Comment: Thank you for clearing it up to me. I no longer gets the warning.

Comment: Great :). Glad i could help!

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should use `keyboardType=this.state.typeOfKeyboard` instead of `keyboardType={this.state.typeOfKeyboard}` , because {some expression} is an object but this.state.typeOfKeyboard is string.
You could have a try.

Comment: what is the difference from using {} and just the this.state ?

Comment: Please know what you are talking about before answering a question. It is not an object, it is JSX's way of outputting data. Just like in angular you do : {{ }}.

Comment: I am sorry to confuse you , but you could have a try in your browser :  `"a"`  is equivalent to `{'a'}` , but when you put an variable in `{}`, they are not equivalent, for example : `a="1"`,  typeof(a) is not equivalent to typeof({a}).

Comment: @WilomGfx You should not mark my answer is not useful = =

Comment: "a" will be equivalent to {"a"} once React has rendered "a", indeed. Beforehand it's not. Doing const potato = 'a big potato' and in the render method doing {potato} will output : 'a big potato'.

Comment: Glad we could come to the same conclusion, now next time make sure you really know the answer before answering as it does not help at all. [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)